# Replace list of items in Pandas dataframe by tree leafs

Tags: python, pandas, replace, tree

I have a tree `Locations` which is has a Continent -> Country -> Location hierarchy. Now I have a dataframe which per row has a list entries of this tree.

How can I replace the entries of the list per row by the leaf's its tree.

My creativity in `apply` or `map` and possible a `lambda` function is lacking.

Minimal example;

```
import pandas as pd

Locations = {
            'Europe':
                {'Germany':      ['Berlin'],
                 'France':       ['Paris','Bordeaux']},
            'Asia':
                {'China':        ['Hong Kong'],
                 'Indonesia':    ['Jakarta']},
            'North America':
                {'United States':['New York','Washington']}}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Persons': ['A', 'B'], 'Locations': [
    ['North America','United States','Asia','France'], 
    ['North America','Asia','Europe','Germany']]})

df = df.apply(...)?
df = df.map(...)?

# How to end up with:
pd.DataFrame({'Persons': ['A', 'B'], 'Locations': [
    ['New York','Washington','Hong Kong','Jakarta','Paris','Bordeaux'], 
    ['New York','Washington','Hong Kong','Jakarta','Paris','Bordeaux','Berlin']]})

# Note the order of the locations doesn't matter is also OK
pd.DataFrame({'Persons': ['A', 'B'], 'Locations': [
    ['Jakarta','Washington','Hong Kong','Paris','New York','Bordeaux'],
    ['Jakarta','Berlin','Washington','Hong Kong','Paris','New York','Bordeaux']]})
```

Comment: Are you sure with your desired output? You would only have one row then. Did you mean `pd.DataFrame({'Persons':['A', 'B'], 'Locations': [['New York','Washington','Hong Kong','Jakarta','Paris','Bordeaux'], ['New York','Washington','Hong Kong','Jakarta','Paris','Bordeaux','Berlin']]})`?

Comment: Yes apologies, you are correct, fixed it.

Comment: What if you have ['Europe', 'Germany']? Do you want to map this to ['Berlin'] only or to ['Berlin', 'Paris','Bordeaux']

Comment: The latter indeed, `['Berlin', 'Paris', 'Bordeaux']`. Apologies (again)  failed to mention that use-case.

Comment: I was asking because of the mapping from ['North America','United States'] to ['New York','Washington']. I assume duplicates should be removed?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thought that use case was clear from that entry, but because I removed an country from North America and had to remove all IP content it was not covered anymore.

Comment: I provided an approach that should solve your issue. In general I think it would be a good start to change the structure of your dictionary (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need the `apply` method. You can start by changing the structure of your `Locations` dictionary in order to map the actual values to your exploded data frame. Then, just combine several `explode`, `drop_duplicates` and `groupby` statements with different aggregation logics to produce your desired result.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

Locations = {
    'Europe':{'Germany': ['Berlin'], 'France': ['Paris','Bordeaux']},
    'Asia': {'China': ['Hong Kong'], 'Indonesia': ['Jakarta']},
    'North America': {'United States': ['New York','Washington']}
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Persons':['A', 'B'], 'Locations': [['North America','United States','Asia','France'], ['North America','Asia','Europe']]})

mapping_locs = defaultdict(list)

for key, val in Locations.items():
    mapping_locs[key] = list(chain.from_iterable(list(val.values())))
    for lkey, lval in val.items():
        mapping_locs[lkey] = lval
    

(
    df.assign(
        mapped_locations=(
            df.explode("Locations")["Locations"].map(mapping_locs).reset_index()
            .explode("Locations").drop_duplicates(subset=["index", "Locations"])
            .groupby(level=0).agg({"index": "first", "Locations": list})
            .groupby("index").apply(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x["Locations"])))
        )
    )
)
```

Output:

```py
    Persons  Locations                                     mapped_locations
0   A        [North America, United States, Asia, France]  [New York, Washington, Hong Kong, Jakarta, Par...
1   B        [North America, Asia, Europe]                 [New York, Washington, Hong Kong, Jakarta, Ber...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, works perfectly. Didn't thought myself of basically flattening the tree structure. Indeed that helps to simplify it.